# How are vendor IDs assigned for USB devices?

Tags: usb, hardware

I am developing the firmware for a USB-based hardware device. The USB interface protocol requires that each device be assigned a vendor ID (VID) and product ID (PID).

How do I, as a device manufacturer/designer/developer, acquire a vendor ID? It is my understanding that the USB-IF assigns and policies these; is that correct? Do I need to buy a vendor ID from the USB-IF?

What happens if, instead, I just randomly pick a vendor ID to assign to my device, or just enter 0x0000, 0xFFFF?

Comment: The assignment process rather outrageous and far too expensive. Despite the 2K bribe, there appears to be no public vendor table.

Comment: It's not $2000, it's really $5000. It's $2000 per VID if you join USB-IF and pay a $4000 annual membership fee (thus your 1st VID is actually $6k). You can just buy a VID w/o joining for $5000... as most companies only need one, this is the least-cost way to go BUT you aren't allowed to use the "USB certified" logo.

Comment: Came across this [link](http://www.oshwa.org/2013/11/19/new-faq-on-usb-vendor-id-and-product-id), might be worth a read

Comment: If you are producing a small volume of products Atmel will sublicense a VID/PID pair for free.

Comment: @John, several microcontroller/chip vendors do that, but (AFAIK) they all limit your production quantity to 10,000 units. (Including Atmel - it's not clear from their website, but I got an answer from their support team.)

Comment: I found on Google that some company is letting anyone use its vendor id as long as you comply to some rules written here: https://github.com/obdev/v-usb/blob/master/usbdrv/USB-IDs-for-free.txt
So anyone can make their custom usb device without paying a lot of money for a vendor id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vendor IDs are a scarce resource, just like OUIs (top 3 octets of MAC address) and IPv4 addresses are. They have to be allocated so others don't use IDs/addresses that collide with yours. The cost just raises the barrier to allocation, so everybody doesn't land-grab willy-nilly.

It would be nice to have a "private" range, much like RFC1918 addresses (10/8, 172.16/12, and 192.168/16), that people who don't care about collisions can use.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a law that prohibits anyone or any company from using a random vendor ID? If so, where can I find the text for the law?

Comment: @user613857 If you pick a vendor ID that collides with another company, expect to be sued by them.  Also, the USB logo is trademarked by the USB-IF, so if you misuse it, expect to be hearing from their lawyer.

Comment: The sad thing is that vendor IDs are only scarce due to the original design of the USB standard.  They chose to make the vendor ID be 16 bits.  They should have used more bits, and let anyone pick any VID, and perhaps provided a public website for registering them to avoid collisions (even though such collisions are extremely unlikely if you have enough bits).  When you make a device that uses WinUSB, you generally have to pick a 128-bit Device Interface GUID for your Windows driver, and you are allowed to pick whatever value you want; Microsoft does not police it.

Comment: I expect the decision to only use 16 bits was deliberate so they could justify charging to manage a scarce resource. There's no technical reason not to use 32 bits, or 128. Or even a string like "com.example.myproduct" as Java does.

Comment: It's a good reason, with the modern popularity of open hardware and FPGAs, to abandon USB.

Answer (score 3):

The only meaning of getting a vid and a pid is to ensure that your sub device will not affect other with the same vid and pid.

You could set the vid or pid you like but you get the risk of a collision and your driver or the one of the other device could stop working, or both.

Ref: http://www.usb.org/developers/usbfaq#12

Answer (score 3):

One other answer that people have missed:  It takes a surprising amount of money and time to run a standards body.

1. There are costs to host the web site and official repository for the standard.  You have to setup your own server, or rent space with a hosting company.
2. A new standard requires ***marketing***.  If people do not hear about your standard, how are they going to adopt it and use it?

   Are you going to demo the new USB standard at [CES](http://www.cesweb.org/), [IDF](http://newsroom.intel.com/docs/DOC-5256), [Embedded World](http://www.embedded-world.de/en/), or some other trade show?  It costs ***tens of thousands of dollars*** to rent a booth and pay for construction at one of the big shows.  It costs thousands in air travel and hotels.

   Are you handing out pamphlets at the show?  How much does it cost to have them printed?

   Are you going to advertise your standard in a magazine?  Or banners on a web site?  How do you expect to pay for this?
3. It costs money to coordinate meetings between the various members of your standards body.  If you want a face-to-face meeting, you have to rent a conference room somewhere.  Are you providing snacks and coffee?  If you want to do a conference call, who is paying for the phone service?
4. You probably have an e-mail list or discussion forum.  Who is maintaining that?  How are you paying for the disk space to archive everything?
5. Does your standards body have a mailing address?  Office?  PO Box?  Phone Number?  Fax number?  How do you expect to pay for that?
6. Any standards body with more than 1-2 members is going to have a board of directors, bylaws, officers, etc.  Who is running all of that?
7. At some point, you will want to incorporate your standards body so it is a "perpetual" organization, not just tied to you personally.  That means you need to file a tax return.  Who is paying for the attorney's fees?  Do you want liability insurance?
8. For a "physical" standard like USB, you probably need to spend money building prototype connectors and testing them.  You probably need a test lab somewhere with [oscilloscopes](http://www.tek.com/oscilloscope#all) and other equipment, not to mention PCs, cables, and other equipment.  Before you build the connectors, you probably want to simulate them, both mechanically and electrically.  ***The costs for doing this can exceed $100,000.***
9. Are you designing the logo for the standard yourself in MS Paint?  Or do you want a graphic designer to do it for you.  Who's paying for it?
10. Do you want to register your logo as a trademark?  Who is going to take [pay the fees](http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/tm_fee_info.jsp) for that?

Beyond money, it takes a lot of time to run a standards body.  In the beginning, you might be able to handle it in your spare time, but for a high-visibility standard like USB, you may need someone dedicated to the standards body full time.  They will need a salary.

**The money to run a standards body has to come from somewhere.**

You can charge membership dues, but this may not be enough.  You will find that only a handful of people actually want to contribute to the standard.  Everyone else will simply download the spec from your web site and benefit freely from your hard work.

You can charge for Access to the Specs, but this gets the "open standards" people up in arms.  It also hampers the adoption of your spec.  Not to mention people will probably just share the PDF illegally.

The simple truth is that a $4,000 annual membership fee is a pittance for a USB device manufacturer.  You will spend far more than that designing your product and manufacturing it.  The people who balk at that cost were probably not serious about building a USB device anyway, and would just "waste" the USB vendor ID (there is a finite number of possible IDs).

Comment: The USB-IF probably gets a lot of money from the big companies that make USB devices.  These companies have a keen interest in keeping the standards body healthy.  Check out the USB-IF's animated gif with logos of all the "USB Promoters" on this page: https://www.usb.org/members_landing

Comment: Due to antitrust, they probably do not get much special funding beyond the published membership dues.  That also undermines the concept of an open standards body.  If there is a "donation" to the group, it would be technology that is developed and turned over to the standards body (e.g. Intel and ECHI).  There are 738 members, which equates to ~$2.9M per year.  https://www.usb.org/members_landing/directory/companies_list_form

Answer (score 2):

I've never found an official public listing of VIDs.
Seems to me that usb.org should provide one as a general service to the USB community, and if a vendor didn't want their VID public usb.org could just list it as "private" (it could well happen that a company wants a VID for internal use only)

The best list I've found for VIDs (and many associated PIDs) is here:
http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids
It's updated frequently, but I have found errors, so caveat emptor.

Comment: You can find the text list of VIDs (in decimal value) through [this link on usb.org](http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/comp_dump).

Comment: @Preston It must be very out of date though.  I don't see Sparkfun, Arduino, or my own company on the list.  There are only 738 entries and they are sorted incorrectly.

Comment: Those 738 entries probably correspond to the 738 official members of the USB-IF:  https://www.usb.org/members_landing/directory/companies_list_form   You don't have to be a member to get a VID though, so there are many VIDs missing from that list.

Comment: The links the comments are broken. The current VID list can be found here: [USB.org -> Developers](https://usb.org/developers) -> Valid USB Vendor ID Numbers